# check if given date does not exists with in the two date field

Tags: mysql

Hi friends just i don't know the query to check given date doesn't exists given date field 
in mysql .can any one help me to find out   i have two table 1.Marriage Hall and Booking 
hall id is the primary key in hall table  and foreign key in booking table .how to join two table . my question is 1.Retrieve the available marriage halls for the date 01-15-2013

```
booking_From      booking_to            
2012-10-12       2012-10-15         
2012-10-17       2012-10-19
```

to check the given date  '2012-10-12'  doesn't exists above the date

Answer (score 1):

try

```
select * from <your_table> where '2012-10-12' between `From` and `to`
```

## [SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1badd/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
Here, we are find out date betwwen range of date or not.
If any record is exists then we count no of record is greater then o then date is exists otherwise date is not exists using case function :

   select (case when count(*) <=0 then 'Date is not exists' else 'Date is exists' end) as
     'exists' from given_date where `From` >= '2012-10-12' and  `to` <= '2012-10-12'
```

Comment: While this likely answers the question it's possibly better to explain *why* or provide informative links.

Comment: but i want to fetch the marriage hall name .how can i do this?

Comment: Please enter columname :                                          select (case when count(*) <=0 then columnname else 'Date is exists' end) as
     'exists' from given_date where `From` >= '2012-10-12' and  `to` <= '2012-10-12'

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yourtable where `from`='2012-10-12' or `to`='2012-10-12';
```

Comment: `from` and `to` are invalid column names, they're SQL keywords. I also think you've misunderstood the question, this isn't an equality test, it looks like a range exclusion. Probably best delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the OR conditional operator as

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE FROM = YourDate OR To = YourDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  CASE DoesExist
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Exists'
    ELSE 'Doesnt Exist'
  END AS 'Exists or not?'
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 AS DoesExist
    FROM tAble
    WHERE EXISTS 
    (
         SELECT Date 
         FROM Table WHERE `FROM` >= '20121012' AND `To` <= '20121012'
    )
) t
```